# how to get examples for augmented reality in android

Tags: android, augmented-reality

In my application I want to implement augmented reality concept.In my application if I concentrate on an image that should be detected and it should display related image or video of that image. I searched a lot for augment reality examples but I did not get related example. Please help to get augmented reality.To achieve augmented reality is necessary to import any library files and SDK versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html) sdk for android.

Among other things it allows to catch frames from the phone camera and do some manipulation on those frames before rendering them. So you can draw something on the frame. There's a sample where they get video from camera then do some action on that video.

I don't know if this is a good choice for your task, that's the only one I know of, never dealt with AR.

Comment: Thanks for your response.i already tried for opencv but for opencv i didnt get related examples.

Comment: The sdk comes with examples. See how they apply filters to the video then instead put some bitmap over the video

Comment: yes i tried already all examples but there is no example of recognize image and performing related action for that image

Comment: i need to add specific images in database and action should be performed only on those images

Comment: You basically wan't other people to do all of the work for you. listen you WONT get that. buy a book on image recognition from amazon or something